# 'geckodriver.exe binary cannot be found in PATH' when attempting to automate firefox browser with Appium

Tags: java, appium, geckodriver

I have been scratching my head with this issue, I can get chrome app running but firefox will not. I have added geckodriver.exe to my path variables (both user and system), install Firefox 64bit, and done all prerequisites to run appium tests (including reading this [appium guide](http://appium.io/docs/en/drivers/gecko/)). I realise through searching the web this is a recent appium update, so I feel a bit like I'm in uncharted territory.

Below is the code I have along with the error message when attempting to run (TestNG)

```
public class test {

public AndroidDriver<MobileElement> driver;
public WebDriverWait                wait;

@BeforeMethod
public void setup() throws MalformedURLException {
    DesiredCapabilities caps = new DesiredCapabilities();
    System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver", "C:\\Users\\Jack\\Downloads\\drivers\\geckodriver.exe");
    
    caps.setCapability("deviceName", "sdk_gphone_x86");
    caps.setCapability("udid", "emulator-5554"); //DeviceId from "adb devices" command
    caps.setCapability("platformName", "Android");
    caps.setCapability("platformVersion", "11.0");
    caps.setCapability("automationName", "Gecko");
    caps.setCapability("browserName", "firefox");
    caps.setCapability("skipUnlock", "true");
    caps.setCapability("noReset", "false");

    driver = new AndroidDriver<MobileElement>(new URL("http://127.0.0.1:4723/wd/hub"), caps);
    wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 10);
}

@Test
public void basicTest() throws InterruptedException {
    TimeUnit.SECONDS.sleep(5);
}

@AfterMethod
public void teardown() {
    driver.quit();
}
}
```

Error

> org.openqa.selenium.SessionNotCreatedException: Unable to create a new remote session. Please check the server log for more details. Original error: An unknown server-side error occurred while processing the command. Original error: geckodriver.exe binary cannot be found in PATH. Please make sure it is present on your system

[image: Path variable]
[image: gecko driver in variable path]

Server Log

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Go to Environment variables->System variables->Path variable->Click on edit->Give the path of geckodriver.exe folder(do mention the folder name where geckodriver.exe resides) Ex:- C://Users//Downloads//GeckodriverFolder

Create another system variable "geckodriver" and provide the same path of geckodriver.exe stored folder.

Apply changes and restart IDE and execute the testcase.